# Does MATLAB lock files when it opens them (Linux)?

Tags: file, matlab, locking, fopen

I'm collecting data and would like to plot the results in Matlab as they're being collected. However it seems like the file would be locked while my scripts are running. Does anyone know if the Linux version of Matlab acts differently when it opens files, and leaves them writeable by other processes?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is Memory Mapping. It allows other applications to share the same data file with MATLAB.

See MATLAB documentation on [Memory Mapping](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/overview-of-memory-mapping.html) and how to create [MEMMAPFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/memmapfile.html) object.